# Millions of random numbers generated "overflow" rand_r?

Tags: c++, boost

I am having trouble with rand_r. I have a simulation that generates millions of random numbers. I have noticed that at a certain point in time, these numbers are no longer uniform. What could be the problem?

What i do: i create an instance of a generator and give it is own seed.

```
mainRGen= new nativeRandRUni(idumSeed_g);
```

here is the class/object def:

```
class nativeRandRUni {

    public:
        unsigned seed;

        nativeRandRUni(unsigned sd){ seed= sd; }
        float genP() { return (rand_r(&seed))/float(RAND_MAX); } // [0,1]
        int genI(int R) { return (rand_r(&seed) % R); } // [0,R-1]
};
```

numbers are simply generated by:

```
newIntNumber= mainRGen->genI(desired_max);
newFloatNumber= mainRGen->genP();
```

the simulations have the problem described above. I know this is happening cause i have checked the distribution of the generated numbers after the point in time that a signature is shown in the results (see this, top image, http://ubuntuone.com/0tbfidZaXfGNTfiVr3x7DR)

also, if i print the seed at t-1 and t, being t the time point of the signature, i can see the seed changing by an order of magnitude from value 263069042 to 1069048066

if i run the code with a different seed, the problem is always present but at different time points

Also, if i use rand() instead of my object, all goes well... i DO need the object cause sometimes i used threads. The example above does not have threads.

i am really lost here, any clues?

**EDIT** - **EDIT**
it can be reproducible by looping enough times, problem is that, like i said, it takes millions of iterations for the problem to arise. For seed -158342163 i get it at generation t=134065568. One can check numbers generated before (uniform) and after (not uniform). I get the same problem if i change the seed manually at given t's, see (*) in code. Something i also do not expect to happen?

```
#include <tr1/random>
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class nativeRandRUni {

    public:
        unsigned seed;
        long count;

        nativeRandRUni(unsigned sd){ seed= sd; count=0; }
        float genP() { count++; return (rand_r(&seed))/float(RAND_MAX); } // [0,1]
        int genI(int R) { count++; return (rand_r(&seed) % R); } // [0,R-1]

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    long timePointOfProblem= 134065568;

    nativeRandRUni* mainRGen= new nativeRandRUni(-158342163);
    int rr;

    //ofstream* fout_metaAux= new ofstream();
    //fout_metaAux->open("random.numbers");
    for(int i=0; i< timePointOfProblem; i++){
            rr= mainRGen->genI(1009200);
            //(*fout_metaAux) << rr << endl;
            //if(i%1000==0) mainRGen->seed= 111111; //(*) FORCE    
    }
    //fout_metaAux->close();

}
```

Comment: Can you write a small program with a function that shows this anomaly?

Comment: Could you post the value of `seed` at `timePointOfProblem - 10` or so?  Might make it quicker to see what's going on behind the scenes without having to burn though 134mil iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that random numbers is key to your simulation, you should implement your own generator. I don't know what algorithm rand_r is using, but it could be something pretty crappy like linear congruent generator.

I'd look into implementing something fast and with good qualities where you know the underlying algorithm. I'd start by looking at implementing Mersenne Twister:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister

Its simple to implement and very fast - requires no divides.

Comment: Why not use the boost or C++ implementation rather than reinventing the wheel though?

Comment: I agree; if you're using C++11, there's a whole collection of random number generators in the standard library. If you're not, then Boost.Random has pretty much the same set.

Comment: You could - if you wanted to go through the trouble to become dependent on boost. But then you don't have complete control over the algorithm. It takes maybe one day to implement mersenne twister - and another day to implement the statistical measures to verify it. I did.

Answer (score 1):

ended up trying a simple solution from boost, changing the generator to:

```
class nativeRandRUni {
    public:
        typedef mt19937 EngineType;
        typedef uniform_real<> DistributionType;
        typedef variate_generator<EngineType, DistributionType> VariateGeneratorType;

        nativeRandRUni(long s, float min, float max) : gen(EngineType(s), DistributionType(min, max)) {}
        VariateGeneratorType gen;
};
```

I don't get the problem anymore... tho it solved it, i dont feel very comfortable with not understanding what it was. I think Rafael is right, i should not trust rand_r for this intensive number of generations

Now, this is slower than before, so i may look for ways of optimizing it. 
**QUESTION**: Would a Mersenne Twister implementation in principle be faster?

and thanks to all!

Comment: Simple RNG's are generally faster, as they work on a far smaller state. But it's exactly this small state that makes them poor. The Mersenne Twister uses 624 integers of state, in comparison.

Comment: Isn't the `mt19937` in your EngineType already a Mersenne Twister implementation? If you want "good" pseudo-random numbers you have to be prepared to pay a small performance cost.

Comment: Yeah mt19937 is a MT, was just wondering if any of you had the experience of implementing a faster one. Its ok tho, i am happy for now. Thanks!